# invalid IMEI error after factory reset?

Tags: android, reset

i am using the following code to factory reset android phone in my app:

```
try{
                        DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
                        ComponentName androidAdmin;
                        devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                        androidAdmin = new ComponentName(context,
                                AndroidAdminReceiver.class);

                        devicePolicyManager.wipeData(AdminMainActivity.ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Factory Reseting your device: "+AndroidAdminReceiver.adminStatus,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){  
                        Toast.makeText(context, "cant Factory Reset: " + AndroidAdminReceiver.adminStatus,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

it works fine but after the reset process is completed; android phone won't recognize any sim card inserted and gives an error of Invalid IMEI.

1) how do i fix this error on phone?
2) what variation should be done in this code so it wont happen the next time?

Comment: I'd try factory reseting the phone again from the settings menu and see if that fixes it.  If not, return it to the manufacturer as apparently defective *and don't do this again*.

Comment: already tried factory reset through the menu.. doesn't work

Comment: Then this really sounds like a defective device, rather than a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a developer but it seems that somehow you are affecting the /efs folder where the main IMEI is storage.  /efs are unique to each device, so the best thing i can tell you before you start to test another device is make a backup of your entire EFS folder before do anything.